# Visualised timeline with HTML only

Tags: html

Is it possible to create somewhat visualised timeline using HTML only. Maybe someone can share some code snippet? I imagine something: Task1 --> Taskt2 --> Task3 but more visualised way using colored tables etc.

Some ideas:
https://www.jotform.com/blog/15-code-snippets-for-timelines-91734/

Comment: The answer to your question, as you put it, would be just "yes". Were you asking for a solution example?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is old-fashioned html :)

```html
<table style="width:50%;height:1000px;text-align:center;margin:auto;border-collapse: collapse;">
  <tr>
    <td style="border:1px solid;border-right:10px solid">2019</td>
    <td style="">&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td style="border-right:10px solid">&nbsp;</td>
    <td style="border:1px solid;border-left:0px">2018</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td style="border:1px solid;border-right:10px solid">2017</td>
    <td style="">&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td style="border-right:10px solid">&nbsp;</td>
    <td style="border:1px solid;border-left:0px">2016</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

**EDIT:** Now horizontal way :)

```html
<table style="width:100%;height:200px;text-align:center;margin:auto;border-collapse: collapse;">
  <tr style="height:100px;">
    <td style="border:1px solid;border-bottom:10px solid">2019</td>
    <td style="border-bottom:10px solid;">&nbsp;</td>
    <td style="border:1px solid;border-bottom:10px solid">2017</td>
    <td style="border-bottom:10px solid;">&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td style="border:1px solid;">2018</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td style="border:1px solid;">2016</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

**EDIT N°2:** Arrows added :)

```html
<table style="width:100%;height:100px;text-align:center;margin:auto;border-collapse: collapse;">
  <tr style="height:100px;">
    <td style="border:1px solid;">2019</td>
    <td style="font-size:xx-large">»</td>
    <td style="border:1px solid;">2018</td>
    <td style="font-size:xx-large">»</td>
    <td style="border:1px solid;">2017</td>
    <td style="font-size:xx-large">»</td>
    <td style="border:1px solid;">2016</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: This is close to what I am looking for. Can it be done horizontal way using arrows?

Answer (score 1):

Creating a timeline only in HTML becomes difficult. To set the look on a website you always need CSS. On the internet you will find many examples of how a timeline can be created with HTML and CSS.

Some Example Sites:

https://freefrontend.com/css-timelines/#vertical-timelines

https://uicookies.com/css-timeline/

Answer (score 1):

You can use this code

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Demo</title>
    <style type="text/css">
        * {
            box-sizing: border-box;
        }
        body {
            background-color: #474e5d;
            font-family: Helvetica, sans-serif;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
        }
        .timeline {
            position: relative;
            max-width: 1200px;
            margin: 0 auto;
        }
        .timeline::after {
            content: '';
            position: absolute;
            width: 6px;
            background-color: white;
            top: 0;
            bottom: 0;
            left: 50%;
            margin-left: -3px;
        }
        .container {
            padding: 10px 40px;
            position: relative;
            background-color: inherit;
            width: 50%;
        }
        .container::after {
            content: '';
            position: absolute;
            width: 25px;
            height: 25px;
            right: -17px;
            background-color: white;
            border: 4px solid #FF9F55;
            top: 15px;
            border-radius: 50%;
            z-index: 1;
        }
        .left {
            left: 0;
        }
        .right {
            left: 50%;
        }
        .left::before {
            content: " ";
            height: 0;
            position: absolute;
            top: 22px;
            width: 0;
            z-index: 1;
            right: 30px;
            border: medium solid white;
            border-width: 10px 0 10px 10px;
            border-color: transparent transparent transparent white;
        }
        .right::before {
            content: " ";
            height: 0;
            position: absolute;
            top: 22px;
            width: 0;
            z-index: 1;
            left: 30px;
            border: medium solid white;
            border-width: 10px 10px 10px 0;
            border-color: transparent white transparent transparent;
        }
        .right::after {
            left: -16px;
        } 
        .content {
            padding: 20px 30px;
            background-color: white;
            position: relative;
            border-radius: 6px;
        }    
        @media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
            .timeline::after {
                left: 31px;
            }
            .container {
                width: 100%;
                padding-left: 70px;
                padding-right: 25px;
            }
            .container::before {
                left: 60px;
                border: medium solid white;
                border-width: 10px 10px 10px 0;
                border-color: transparent white transparent transparent;
            }
            .left::after,
            .right::after {
                left: 15px;
            }
            .right {
                left: 0%;
            }
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="timeline">
        <div class="container left">
            <div class="content">
                <h2>2017</h2>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, quo ei simul congue exerci, ad nec admodum perfecto mnesarchum, vim ea mazim fierent detracto. Ea quis iuvaret expetendis his, te elit voluptua dignissim per, habeo iusto primis ea eam.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="container right">
            <div class="content">
                <h2>2016</h2>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, quo ei simul congue exerci, ad nec admodum perfecto mnesarchum, vim ea mazim fierent detracto. Ea quis iuvaret expetendis his, te elit voluptua dignissim per, habeo iusto primis ea eam.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="container left">
            <div class="content">
                <h2>2015</h2>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, quo ei simul congue exerci, ad nec admodum perfecto mnesarchum, vim ea mazim fierent detracto. Ea quis iuvaret expetendis his, te elit voluptua dignissim per, habeo iusto primis ea eam.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="container right">
            <div class="content">
                <h2>2012</h2>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, quo ei simul congue exerci, ad nec admodum perfecto mnesarchum, vim ea mazim fierent detracto. Ea quis iuvaret expetendis his, te elit voluptua dignissim per, habeo iusto primis ea eam.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="container left">
            <div class="content">
                <h2>2011</h2>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, quo ei simul congue exerci, ad nec admodum perfecto mnesarchum, vim ea mazim fierent detracto. Ea quis iuvaret expetendis his, te elit voluptua dignissim per, habeo iusto primis ea eam.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="container right">
            <div class="content">
                <h2>2007</h2>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, quo ei simul congue exerci, ad nec admodum perfecto mnesarchum, vim ea mazim fierent detracto. Ea quis iuvaret expetendis his, te elit voluptua dignissim per, habeo iusto primis ea eam.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: thanks for this example, but I am not able to use css at all. I am wondering, is it possible to do something similar with pure html. Maybe not so eye catching but similar and horizontal version.

Comment: Back in the days when CSS was not a thing, people used to layout their HTML pages with tables.

Comment: That said, if you use @Piyush Teraiya code without the CSS, it looks just fine

Comment: Not in all cases. For instance, it not look fine in outlook.